# pivot table view from existing table SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot-table

I have a table result from my query which is as follows

```
company1 company2  year  revenue
---------------------------------
A1        B1       2000   1000
B1        A1       2001   2000
A1        C1       2000   1500
C1        A1       2001   1400
```

I want to create yearwise separate pivot tables of from this table of the following view

For 2000

```
    A1    B1     C1
A1        1000   1500
B1 1000
C1 1500
```

For 2001

```
    A1    B1     C1
A1        2000   1400
B1 2000
C1 1400
```

Can someone suggest a query to automate the result or a generic query which can be used to obtain the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is straightforward a little bit but working :)

```
create table my_query (
    company1 nvarchar(100),
    company2 nvarchar(100),
    [year]  int,
    revenue int,
);

insert into my_query (company1, company2, [year], revenue) values ('A1', 'B1', 2000, 1000);
insert into my_query (company1, company2, [year], revenue) values ('B1', 'A1', 2001, 2000);
insert into my_query (company1, company2, [year], revenue) values ('A1', 'C1', 2000, 1500); 
insert into my_query (company1, company2, [year], revenue) values ('C1', 'A1', 2001, 1400);

----------------------------------------------------------------
create procedure yearwise
    @year int
as
begin
    declare @code nvarchar(max);
    set @code = '';

    select @code = @code + [code] from (
        select 'select src.company' [code], 1 [sort]
        union
        select ', (select sum(revenue) [sum] from my_query where [year] = '+cast(@year as nvarchar)+' and ((company1 = src.company and company2 = '''+company1+''') or (company1 = '''+company1+''' and company2 = src.company))) ['+company1+']', 2 from my_query
        union 
        select 'from (select company1 [company] from my_query union select company2 from my_query) as src', 3
    ) as tbl
    order by [sort]

    exec (@code);
end
----------------------------------------------------------------

exec yearwise @year = 2001
```

Result

```
company A1      B1      C1
----------------------------
A1      NULL    2000    1400
B1      2000    NULL    NULL
C1      1400    NULL    NULL
```